# Can't reset auto increment of a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, auto-increment

I deleted a bunch of old entries and now the count is all messed up. This didn't reset the count:

`ALTER TABLE $usermail AUTO_INCREMENT = '1'`

Why is it not resetting it? Is it because the row `email_count` has the index key? Are there other ways to reset an auto_increment count?

Comment: Messing with the auto increment should only be done when really necessary and when you know what you are doing. Why do it? Having gaps in your records is no reason at all

Comment: What count? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Remove the quotes around the `1`. It's a syntax error.

Comment: @BillKarwin I tried that didn't work.

Comment: @Dharman I want the auto_increment to be reset.

Comment: Do you want the next generated number to be 1 or do you want the existing values to change?